# Mapping Multi Tenant Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

> Well we are developing a Multi Tenant Application with Separate 
>   Databases. All the schema have the same structure for the N separate 
>   databases.  We are using MySql with aspx to build a web application.
>   Now  there will be a situation when there may be same users who are on
>   N  separate databases.  We need a approach to link up those databases 
>   where the user have   his/her datas and show it on a dropdownlist.
>   After linking the database   when the  user login he/she will able to
>   see all the available database   in the dropdownlist where his/her
>   data reside.  When the user change the dropdownlist values he/she
>   should be able to  change the database instantly and view his/her
>   datas form the linked  databases.   We have built the Multi Tenant
>   Application and every thing is going fine.   The problem is that how
>   to map all those database from a master database   for the particular
>   user. Every user has a separate Unique ID in the separate   database.
>   So user don't have anything common in the Multi Tenant   Database
>   other than the data structure. We tried storing all users   Unique ID
>   in the master database and linking it with the other   Unique ID where
>   the user reside but the solution is not  giving fruitful results. Any
>   other alternative is most welcome.

Comment: please format so the text is readable.

Comment: Perhaps a database with a table that links userid's across the various databases?

Comment: we tried that one but then we can not retrieve the first database userID

Answer (score 0):

The method I went with for multi-tenant mysql is:

- main database with all of the data all tenants, but every table has a `tenantID` column which separates out the data by tenant
- create multiple databases for each tenant, but that database is filled with mysql views that reference back to the main database. For example:

.

```
 # ie. main database has tables: users, and invoices
 # if you have a new tenant named "acme", then:
 create database acme;
 create view acme.users as select * from maindb.users where entityID=2;
 create view acme.invoices as select * from maindb.invoices where entityID=2;
```

In my situation, this allowed me not have to change any of my previous queries (which were built before I knew I was going to use multi-tenant). All I had to do was select the proper database, and all the data was automatically separate.

But keeping the actual data all in the same database, this simplified maintenance.